# Google Maps pan control does not display

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google maps with this options :

```
mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.92553, 32.86628),
        zoom: 6,
        panControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    };
```

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);

I want to this control  :

[image: I want This Control]

I want to this control but not showing my map.

Or  I want to journey with button on map.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your are using a version of Google Maps newer than `3.22`.

After that version as stated in the release notes, the Pan Control is no longer available. To continue to use it you must request an earlier version.

> The Pan control on the map is no longer available. To pan the view,
>   users click and drag, or swipe, the map. (Note that the Pan control in
>   Street View remains available.)

At the time of this answer we are at version `3.37`and `3.22` is already retired.