# Pan control not visible in google map API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map api where there is a requirement to add a pan control inside my map however after setting panControl: true.I am not able to see the pan control anywhere in map. Please see this to understand the issue [Google Map API Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373751/google-maps-pan-control-does-not-display)

I am expecting a pan control similar to highlighted in below question.

[Pan control not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373751/google-maps-pan-control-does-not-display)

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: its same as whatever done on w3schools site. The one which I linked as  Google Map API Demo. you can see there also pan control is not visible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version 3.22 the panControl has been **depreciated** and can no longer be used.

It is not listed on the googleAPI controls page and the release notes confirm this [View here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases).

[image]